# How can I use my own email template in Magento 1.7.2 email function?

Tags: php, magento, email

Hi to all out there :)

I am using a php script in order to send to a customers group an email with their new credentials.

The command that I use and sends the email is below:

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

This sents an email to a customer and uses the template called "New Account"

**The question is that I have created a new custom template** 
called **Send password to Resellers template**

So how can I run this command 
`$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();` 
but use my new template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify an option in the database to use the new template, here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-send-confirmation-email-to-new-account-subscribers

Answer (score 1):

**If you are tring to have both a 'new order' and 'reseller' template**, one way to accomplish this would be :

Create a new module that extend `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`

```
 class MagePal_ResellerCustomer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
      const XML_PATH_REGISTER_RESELLERS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customerreseller/create_account/email_template';

    public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
    {
        $types = array(
            'registered'   => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_RESELLERS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,  // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled
            'confirmed'    => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
            'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,   // email with confirmation link
        );
        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
        }

        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl), $storeId);

        return $this;
    }
```

Add a System Configuration to your module so you can select your custom email template (see [Custom Magento System Configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration))

in system.xml

```
<email_template>
    <label>Email Template</label>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
</email_template>
```

Then to send your email do

```
if(customer group == reseller):
   $customer = Mage::getModel('resellercustomer/customer')->load($customer_id)
   $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
else
   $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id)
   $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

**If you just want to use your new template take a look** @ [Customizing Email Templates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails)

> Admin menu > System > Config > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options.